# chrome extension: when does a persistent background script stop running?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, local-storage

If my chrome extension has a persistent background script, I could use it to store data in the script that I would eventually want to store in chrome.storage.local. When / what event triggers the background script to stop running (so that I can add a callback to store the data in chrome.storage.local before the local data goes out of scope)?

Comment: There's no such event that can be used reliably so just save the data immediately.

Answer (score 1):

Background scripts can either be registered persistent (always running while the extension is enabled and has not crashed) or non-persistent (not always but temporarily runs when `runtime.getBackgroundPage` or any runtime event callback registerd in the background script is invoked)

They are registered in the manifest under the "background" field, and "persistent" should be specified as `false` for non-persistent background scripts/pages.

```
}
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "persistent": false
  }
}
```

There is a runtime event callback for when the **non-persistent** background script is unloaded (because they unload on their own after a few seconds of inactivity), it does not get invoked when an extension with persistent background script is disabled (or crashed of-course).

```
chrome.runtime.onSuspend.addListener(function() {
    console.log("Unloading.");
});
```

You can verify that with this simple extension:

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "name": "onSuspend",
  "description": "onsuspent",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "permissions": [
    "storage"
  ],
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "persistent": true
  }
}
```

**background.js**

```
chrome.runtime.onSuspend.addListener(function() {
  console.log("Unloading.");
  chrome.storage.local.set({"Saved": "yes"}, function() {});
});

chrome.storage.local.get("Saved", function(data) {
  console.log("shouldn't be an empty object": data);
});
```

The only way I found that you can register a callback to run before the persistent background script is disabled is by loading a background page instead and using the window's unload event, code use for testing:

```
{
  "name": "callback before stopping persistent background script",
  "description": "callback before stopping persistent background script",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "permissions": [
    "storage"
  ],
  "background": {
    "page": "background.html",
    "persistent": true
  }
}
```

**background.js**

```
window.addEventListener('unload', function(event) {
  localStorage.setItem("Saved", "yes");
});
console.log("Saved:", localStorage.getItem('Saved'));
```

**background.html**

```
<html><body></body><script src="background.js"></script></html>
```

To test it try disabling and re-enabling or reloading the extension twice.

Comment: You can't use asynchronous API such as chrome.storage inside onSuspend, see the documentation.

Comment: @wOxxOm aha, I remember reading something in the docs that mentioned async 
 runtime APIs are not guaranteed to run, so am I right in claiming that onSuspend only runs for non-persistent scripts? the docs does not mention otherwise. so I had to test it to verify my assumption by testing, I tried other things like console.log and alert to see if the onSuspend's callback gets called when disabling/reloading, but they obviously didn't work, and I had no ideas what I could use other than storage.local.